# C Array of string

Tags: c, string

This is maybe simple question but  I want to create two dimensional array and add it string like in java

```
string  str = "text" ; 

string [][] array  = new [][] string ;  

array[i][j] = str ;
```

But in C there is no string .I tried like this  but here  strcpy() gives error.It returns to assembly code. I am trying to read line by line from text and split line by space and add them to structure.But first I think that I must add each line and row in array and then making iteration and adding to structures fields.

```
static const char filename[] = "student.txt";
FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );
char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
char delims [ ]=" ";
char *result =NULL;
char list[15];
char arra[128][128];
int i=0;
int j=0;

struct {
    char gruppa[10];
    char familiya[20];
    int uchaste;
    struct {
        int firsth;
        int second;
        int third;
        int fourht;
        int fifth;
    } exam;
}student;

for(i=0; i<128; i++)
    for(j=0; j<128; j++) 
        arra[i][j] = '\0';

for(i=0; i<15; i++)
    list[i] = '\0';


if ( file != NULL )
{           
    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) 
    {
        result = strtok(line,delims);
        while (result !=NULL) {         
            strcpy(list,("%s",result));
                strcpy(arra[i][j],list); // Here it gives errror 
            j++;
            result = strtok(NULL,delims);
        }
        j=0;
        i++;
    }
    fclose ( file );        
}
else
{
    perror ( filename ); 
}
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: did you try sprintf function?

Comment: It seems you are doing this a bit too complicated. It would be easier for you directly put in the strings into your structure instead of storing them in the array. You could also to make it more flexible make by making the structs nodes in a linked list

Answer (score 4):

The strings in C are arrays of `char`, so your `char arra[128][128];` specifies an array of 128 strings, each with length up to 127 characters + the terminating `'\0'`. If you want 128×128 strings, you need a third dimension.

If you don't mind allocating a fixed amount of memory for every string, then you can just add the third dimension to the existing definition: `char array[128][128][max_length_of_string + 1]`

(Note that in that case you must ensure that the maximum length is not exceeded, C will not check it for you!)

If you wish to allocate the strings dynamically, you can make the elements `char *` (i.e. pointers to char): `char *array[128][128]`, but then you must `malloc` memory for each string (not forgetting the extra `char` for the trailing `'\0'` that C strings have). And `free` all of them when you are done (unless you just exit the program at that point).

Comment: NO. I want to cerate array that each record will keep string  like array[0][0] = str1 , array[0][1]=str2

Comment: @Meko: I edited my post to include an alternative way that allows you to do that. However, if you have `a[128][128][64]`, you *can* do `strcpy(a[0][0], str);` like you are trying to do now, you just need to ensure that the string is at most 63 chars long. Like I said, C strings *are* arrays of characters.

Comment: A C string is not a data type.  It's a data *layout*. A string is "a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character".  A char array may *contain* a string.  So strictly speaking, you can have an array of char arrays, where each element contains a string, but you cannot have an array of strings.